# Flutter - Convert Java routine to flutter

Tags: java, android, flutter, flutter-channel

I have an android java pattern that I would like to convert to something similar in flutter.  It's pretty straight forward but I am having difficulty finding a clear example.  What this involves is having a utility class that does repetitive string manipulation routines that I can use anywhere in the project.

Here is an example.  I use the CapEachWord routine in a lot of source members.   See the arrow below.

```
import com.auto.accident.report.util.utils;
   @Override
    public void onResults(Bundle results) {

        ArrayList<String> result = results
                .getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);


        switch (REQ_CODE) {
           case REQ_CODE_NOTE_SUBJECT: {
                                    DA_RESULT = utils.capEachWord(DA_RESULT);    <-------------------
                        tieAN_SUBJECT.setText(DA_RESULT);
                        startNoteInput();
                        break;
           }

        }
```

CapEachWord resides in a source member called utils and looks like this.

```
public class utils {

   public static String capEachWord(String DA_RESULT) {
        int splitLength;
        int index = 0;
        String[] words = DA_RESULT.split(" ");
        splitLength = words.length;
        StringBuilder DA_RESULTBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        while (index < splitLength) {
            int DA_SIZE = words[index].length();
            words[index] = words[index].substring(0, 
               1).toUpperCase() + 
               words[index].substring(1, 
        DA_SIZE);
            DA_RESULTBuilder.append(words[index]);
            if (index != splitLength) {
                DA_RESULTBuilder.append(" ");
            }
            index++;
        }
        DA_RESULT = DA_RESULTBuilder.toString();

        return DA_RESULT;
    }
}
```

What I need to know is how to properly include the utils, structure the utils member and
and ask for the conversion result.  The actual conversion code I can work out myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can include your utils file with `import './utils.dart';` (by relative path) or `import  'package:your_package_name:path/to/utils.dart';` (for path from `lib` folder).

In your case I would make just class `Utils` or something, with static methods that I could use.

Usage would be simple after proper importing to some source file:

```
//...
myString = Utils.capEachWord(otherString);
```

Comment: Great that works.  Results are being returned.  Thanks.